# use range of cells as criteria in sumif

Tags: excel

I have a column of cells that will line up with a header row for a time period (period 1, period 2, period 3, etc.)  There is a 1 or 0 flag next to it if I want to use this period in my sum formula.

I also have locations listed on my left column.

How can create a sum formula to give me all amounts for a specific location if the period is flagged as 1 in the column next to it?  I am assuming it will be some sort of sumif array, but I have not been successful is writing the formula.

Answer (score 0):

Probably want to use `SUMPRODUCT(zero_one_range, values_range)`.  The 0s will exclude the values you don't want; the 1s will include the other values and then it all gets added up.

Here is a dummy example:

[image: example of SUMPRODUCT]

Formula in cell `G3`

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B3:D3,B6:D6)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is exactly what you have after rereading the question.  You can add additional conditions by forcing them to evaluate to a `0/1`.  This is commonly done with `--(some condition)`, parentheses needed.  The `--` forces a `0/1` out of a `FALSE/TRUE` from a logical.  Full formula: `=SUMPRODUCT(B3:D3,B6:D6, --(some add'l condition))`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Sumifs Function]

I created a spreadsheet based on your description.  This example has 4 columns: Location, Period, In Use and Amount.

We will assume only 3 locations and 3 periods. In Use Status 0 is not in use; 1 is in use.

Let's say we want to see the total amount for CA in period 3 that are in use.  We will use a "sumifs" formula in cell D26 as follow: =SUMIFS(D2:D24,A2:$A$24,"CA",$B$2:$B$24,"3",$C$2:$C$24,"1")

The sum range is our Amount column, criteria range 1 is Location column, criteria is equal to "CA", criteria range 2 is period column, criteria 2 is equal to "3" as period 3, criteria range 3 is In Use column, criteria 3 is equal to "1" as in use.

Comment: What if the periods are listed along the top and the locations on left side?  The numbers would then fill in based on location and period.

Comment: That sounds like something you would do with a pivot table.  For example, we can create a pivot table for the above data: Put Location on the row and Period to the Column of the PT.  Then you can use In Use as filter to filter out to only show status 1.